# Get all documents for _id stored as array values inside the document using elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, sense

Below is my mapping index document sample:

```
{
  "_index": "sample_index",
  "_type": "default",
  "_id": "id-sample-0005",
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
      "name": "Eenst Y kios",
      "ids_mapped": [
         "id-sample-00010",
         "id-sample-00011"
      ]
   }
}
```

I need to write a query that will get the document based on _id passed as parameter and along with that all the _id value exist in "ids_mapped" field.

```
GET sample_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "_id": [
         "id-sample-0005"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Dont know how to write the query above to meet my requirement. Basically in the above query user will pass only the "id-sample-0005" value as parameter and the query should return 3 documents. i.e. [id-sample-0005,id-sample-00010,id-sample-00011].

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @val i know that but i want to achieve in the same query instead of firing another query. am sure there will be a way in order to acheive that. either using painless script or filtered query.

Comment: Can you explain the goal - context ? Maybe you could use parent child or different modelisation. But fore sure if you need to querry document according to the result or one querry, you will have to do 2 querries (as val said)

Comment: seems not possible using single query, I guess i will end up firing 2 query.

Comment: Definitely possible, see my answer ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of achieving this is by leveraging the [`terms` lookup feature](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html#query-dsl-terms-lookup-params).

The following query would return all three documents with id `id-sample-0005`, `id-sample-00010` and `id-sample-00011`:

```
POST sample_index/_search?pretty
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "_id": "id-sample-0005"              <-- input your ID here
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "_id": {
              "index": "sample_index",
              "type": "default",
              "id": "id-sample-0005",            <-- and here
              "path": "ids_mapped.keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The first sub-constraint returns the main document itself and the second sub-constraint will return the documents with the mapped IDs.